# coefficient of $x^{29}$ in the expansion of $(1+x^5+x^7+x^9)^{1000}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

How can I use the multinomial theorem approach here??

Or is there any other method?

Coefficient of  $x^{29}$  in the expansion of  $(1+x^5+x^7+x^9)^{1000}$

Comment: First you need to figure out which combinations can give you $x^{29}$, one is $(x^5)^4*x^9$ but it's not the only one. Then you can use the multinomial theorem to get the coefficeint for each combination.

Comment: It helps to notice that $29$ is odd., so we can only expect an odd number of nontrivial factors.  Next, we notice that $3$ is too few as $3\cdot 9 = 27<29$ and $7$ is too many as $7\cdot 5 = 35$, so there must be exactly five nontrivial factors.  I count a total of 15 possibilities if we ignore $1$'s for the time being and taking order into account.  (*seen by looking at the expansion of $(x^5+x^7+x^9)^5$*).  So, now the remaining question is how many ways we can intersperse the $1$'s inbetween.

Answer (score 5):

By multinomial expansion:
$$\sum \frac{1000!}{a! b! c! d!} (x^5)^a (x^7)^b (x^9)^c (1)^d,~ where~ a+b+c+d=1000~ and ~5a+7b+9c=29.$$ There are two possibilities, $a=4, b=0, c=1, d=995$ and $a=3, b=2, c=0,d=995$ So the required co-efficient is $$\frac{1000!}{4!~ 1!~995!}+ \frac{1000!}{3!~ 2!~995!}=
(\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{3!~2!})\times\frac{1000!}{995!} = \frac{1000!}{8~(995!)}=123754368753000 . $$
Click below to see the expansion of $(1+x^5+x^7+x^9)^{1000}$ in Mathematica.

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0DpH.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0DpH.png)

Comment: The exponent is $29$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{1000!}{4!~ 1!~995!}$

Comment: @robjohn This is incorrect. Now I have added the mathematica clip for the expansion of $(1+x^5+x^7+x^9)^{1000}$ and co-efficient of $x^{29}$ therein.

Comment: $\frac{1000!}{4!~ 1!~996!}$ was incorrect and has evidently been edited.

Answer (score 2):

**Repeated Binomial Theorem**
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+x^5+x^7+x^9\right)^{1000}
&=\sum_i\binom{1000}{i}\left(x^5+x^7+x^9\right)^i\\
&=\sum_i\binom{1000}{i}x^{5i}\left(1+x^2+x^4\right)^i\\
&=\sum_{i,j}\binom{1000}{i}\binom{i}{j}x^{5i}\left(x^2+x^4\right)^j\\
&=\sum_{i,j}\binom{1000}{i}\binom{i}{j}x^{5i+2j}\left(1+x^2\right)^j\\
&=\sum_{i,j,k}\binom{1000}{i}\binom{i}{j}\binom{j}{k}x^{5i+2j+2k}\\
\end{align}
$$
Choosing all $5i+2j+2k=29$ where $i\ge j\ge k\ge0$ limits the sum greatly (two terms, to be precise)
$$
\begin{align}
\left[x^{29}\right]\left(1+x^5+x^7+x^9\right)^{1000}
&=\binom{1000}{5}\binom{5}{2}\binom{2}{0}+\binom{1000}{5}\binom{5}{1}\binom{1}{1}\\[6pt]
&=123754368753000
\end{align}
$$
For me, it was easier to make sure that I got all the terms this way rather than the Multinomial approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If you are open for more advanced methods than multinomial theorem, then you can make an unnormalized Markov chain with hmm.. 30 something states should be enough.

Find it's matrix and take it to the 1000th power times the $[1,0,0,\cdots,0]^T$ vector.

Or maybe diagonalize it or find other suitable canonical form first, to speed up calculations.

Calculating this in Matlab / GNU Octave

```
v = M^1000*[1;zeros(30,1)]
```

gives

$$v(30) = 1.237543687530000 \cdot 10^{14}$$

Which (given that the other answers are indeed correct) means we did not even break the numerical imprecision of our floating point model.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* How many ways can you form $29$ by adding together copies of $0,5,7,9$ so that you have $1000$ summands? Note that you need not consider more than four nonzero summands since $4×9$ is already $36,$ which has exceeded $29.$ Thus, the problem reduces to how many ways to form $29$ using at most four copies of the numbers $5,7,9.$